Typescript: Make children class public methods available with parent static method
I have the following structures:


class Base
{
  constructor(private input: number) {
    // ...
  }

  getInput() {
    // ...
  }

  /**
   * Creat new instance
   */
  public static fromGregory(i: number) {
    //...
    return new this(i);
  }
}

class Child1 extends Base
{
  public getAge() {
    // ...
  }
}

const test = Child1.fromGregory(1);
test.getInput();  // Correct type
test.getAge();   //Type Error: Property 'getAge' does not exist on type 'Base'.



When i make a new instance with child class by calling static method from parent, Typescript unknow about child's public methods. How can I correct type for theme?
Thanks,

Quite simply, you never defined getAge() anywhere, not in the Base class, the extending class, or elsewhere in the example you've provided. You have already shown how TypeScript does recognize the public methods of a class' parent type.

Sorry, I edited my question.

• Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplicate. If not, what am I missing? • What is "Gregory"? Is it someone's name? That's a very strange thing to have in example code. You might want to [edit] to make this a little less distracting.

Thank you for save my time, the problem is resolved. I working on an astronomy project, Gregory reference to Gregorian calendar.
